# Блок каждую секунду меняет координаты

Tags: javascript

див 50*50px,каждую сек,меняет координаты(рандомно),и при клике(попаданию)на див введется счет
нужен код JS (без jQuery)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

        .block{

            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background: red;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0
            left: 0;
        }
        h1{
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ваш счёт:</h1>
    <div class="block"></div>
<script>


</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: нужен - дак напишите

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: пожалуйста. Ознакомьтесь с разделом справки [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Здесь не сервис по решению домашних заданий, потрудитесь начать хотя бы решать самостоятельно, а когда столкнетесь с проблемой, задавайте вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let result = 0;
const resultElement = document.querySelector('h1');

const block = document.querySelector('.block');

const containerWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const containerHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

const getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
  return Math.round(min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}

setInterval(() => {
  block.style.left = getRandomNumber(0, containerWidth - block.offsetWidth) + 'px';
  block.style.top = getRandomNumber(0, containerHeight - block.offsetHeight) + 'px';
}, 1000)

block.addEventListener('click', () => {
  resultElement.textContent = `Ваш счёт: ${++result}`;
})
```

```css
.block{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
  left: 0;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Ваш счёт:</h1>
<div class="block"></div>
```